# php trim(), work poorly

Tags: php, trim

I need cut from page url www. using php trim() function.
But this function cut and first letter, why?

```
$domain = parse_url('http://wordpresas.com/page/1');
$domain['host'] = trim($domain['host'], 'www.');
pr($domain['host']); //ordpresas.com
```

Comment: `trim()` works fine. Your code works poorly

Comment: Heh, interesting. The second parameter to `trim()` is indeed a *character list*, so any character in that list will get cut off. Wasn't aware of that. (Still, this is by design. You'll need a different function to do what you need.)

Answer (score 4):

As other have stated the second parameter of `trim()` contains [a list of characters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) which get trimmed.

However you can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) for this. This will make sure only `www.` will be stripped if the string starts with it.

```
preg_replace('/^www./', '', $domain['host']);
```

Comment: Not sure who downvoted you. While `preg_replace` might be somewhat overkill for this scenario, it's a completely valid answer... Have an equalising +1 good sir!

Comment: @Leigh It's the cleanest option IMHO. (Readability wise). I think the downvoter thinks: but but but think about the perfomance. Ignorance is a bliss :P

Comment: Wouldn't a simple `str_replace('www.','',$domain['host'])` work just as well? No need for regex...?

Comment: @Nick No that wouldn't work. It may strip too much. `www.examplewww.com` would result in: `example.com`.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to do this is probably:

```
if( strncmp( 'www.', $domain['host'], 4) == 0){
    $domain['host'] = substr( $domain['host'], 4);
}
```

It should have complexity `O(1)` :)